# How was JARVIS created?

Tags: marvel, iron-man, artificial-intelligence

I was wondering how J.A.R.V.I.S. was created. The Marvel wiki said that J.A.R.V.I.S. was created by H.A.M.M.E.R. Was Tony Stark involved in its development process?

Comment: In which universe, or which version of JARVIS?

Comment: @phantom42 HAMMER would imply the Marvel comics mainstream (616) universe

Comment: But Marvel Wiki's [Earth-616 J.A.R.V.I.S entry](http://marvel.wikia.com/Just_A_Really_Very_Intelligent_System_%28Earth-616%29) does not mention HAMMER at all.

Comment: OK, Marvel *Universe* (which is a *different* wiki) [does mention HAMMER being responsible for J.A.R.V.I.S](http://marvel.com/universe/Iron_Man_%28Anthony_Stark%29) at the bottom.

Comment: @phantom42 Your cited article does not say HAMMER is responsible for JARVIS. It just happens to mention both of them in the same paragraph.

Comment: @JackBNimble OK, I misread it as saying Osborne's HAMMER provided the suit with Hill. This is still the closest thing I can find to any wiki claming HAMMER created JARVIS.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the Marvel Cinematic Universe (Earth-199999) [J.A.R.V.I.S](http://marvel.wikia.com/Just_A_Rather_Very_Intelligent_System_%28Earth-199999%29) is an AI developed by Tony Stark first primarily as being an artificial assistant in his house, and later modified to perform a lot of functions in the Mark 2 - 47 suits.

In the main Marvel Comic Universe (Earth-616) [J.A.R.V.I.S](http://marvel.wikia.com/Just_A_Really_Very_Intelligent_System_%28Earth-616%29) is an artificial intelligence that Tony Stark creates in order to assist Pepper Potts in using the suit that he built for her (called Rescue). This J.A.R.V.I.S was directly inspired by the one in the first Ironman film.

None of the current cited articles in the comments say that H.A.M.M.E.R created J.A.R.V.I.S.